# Javascript function returning default value instead of currently entered value of a textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a Web page(aspx) with a large amount of JavaScript and Jquery(Used for managing the image scrolling for different sections like Featured products,Special Offers etc)

In the Featured Products section multiple product details are listed .
Each product has an associated text box where the user can enter a quantity that he wants to purchase.

When I try to get the value of a particular text box using JavaScript I get the default value of the text box instead of the value that is currently entered in the text box.

Using J Query also results in the default value being returned.

If the text box is moved to the beginning of the form section the currently entered value in the text box is returned as expected.

Thanks in advance for any tips as to why this is happening

Regards

Mathew

Comment: show you your code to help you

Comment: any the functions code is where?

Comment: Simultaneously too much information and not enough information.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this template was purchased . SO I have extremely limited knowledge of its internal working

Answer (score 0):

Could not find the actual problem. Anyway I am able to access the value that is entered in the textbox using Jquery.

Later I realised that the problem was occuring because the textbox was included in a slideshow
generated using Jquery Cycle2 plugin